# What does Ubuntu use for creating cloud-images?

Tags: cloud, disk-image

How are Ubuntu creating cloud images? Are they using FAI or some custom process? I am interested in creating these images myself. I would like them to have syslinux instead of grub and console=ttyS0 output, so I can use them for Eucalyptus cloud.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the code for building all the cloud images here:

- https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/livecd-rootfs/trunk

See also:

- [How are the Official Ubuntu Vagrant boxes built and published to Atlas?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697454/how-are-the-official-ubuntu-vagrant-boxes-built-and-published-to-atlas/697761#697761)

Comment: thanks, that answers partly, I looked at the tools, seem quite ok. But I would like to know how it is made in Canonical. Is there any information available or is it some proprietary, undisclosed methods ?

Comment: All the code to make images is published on Launchpad, which itself is OSS, there are no proprietary closed methods for the way we make any images.