# Where to find the script to build images like here: https://partner-images.canonical.com/oci/?

Tags: disk-image

Other answers point to [https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/livecd-rootfs/+git/livecd-rootfs/+ref/ubuntu/master](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Eubuntu-core-dev/livecd-rootfs/+git/livecd-rootfs/+ref/ubuntu/master) as the basis.

I cannot locate the scripts found at the links here: [How are the Official Ubuntu Vagrant boxes built and published to Atlas?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697454/how-are-the-official-ubuntu-vagrant-boxes-built-and-published-to-atlas/697761#697761)
Following the links at the Vagrant related answer led me to a forbidden error here: [https://code.launchpad.net/~cloudware/cloudware/+git/jenkins_kvm](https://code.launchpad.net/%7Ecloudware/cloudware/+git/jenkins_kvm)

Comment: What in those links is unclear?  Looks like the one from Jorge has all you need including a link to the scripts you need?  Basically you need ` livecd-rootfs` and compile

Comment: The link in the readme to the new git repo throws a forbidden error when I go there: https://code.launchpad.net/~cloudware/cloudware/+git/jenkins_kvm
Also the question was how to explicitly built those OCI images, not the Vagrant ones from the other questions. Half those links don't work.

Comment: I tried to make the question more clear.